# Update recyclerview from the adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update data in the recyclerview from the adapter, a function inside the adapter to do the update.

It is working properly and data is being added to the database but it is not updating the views, I need to restart the app so that it runs the cursor to get data from the database and load the views.

I figured out that the main problem is the different lists in the adapter and in the main activity. The list from the main activity is controlling the views so that when i update the list in the adapter nothing happens.

'''kotlin

```
private val adapter = Padapter (mainActivityList)
```

and

```
class adapter(private val adapterList:ArrayList)
```

'''
How can I do it ? Should i try to call a function in the main activity ?

I really appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide.

Comment: You should add/remove items in the Adapter's list (the same list read during getView). After updating the list, call notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChanged(position) if you know which position was changed

Comment: You mean update the adapterList and notifyDataSetChanged() ? that is not working

Comment: You should only store the list in the adapter, the activity then retrieves the list from there to display to the recycler view. Adapters are supposed to have data for the view to display if you store the list in the activity then there is no point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as  adam yong suggested in the comments. I stored the list in the adapter.

At first i didnt know how to do that but i discovered somewhere that i had to call the list to the database thought the adapter like this :

In the main activity:

"'Kotlin
adapter.list.addAll( dbHandler!!.cursor())
"'